# open integrated terminal of vs code in current working directory in linux mint

Tags: visual-studio-code

I switched from Windows to linux mint recently. This feature of opening terminal in cwd was working fine in windows. I also used sync to export all my settings to linux mint.

But for some reason, linux bash is not opening in cwd.
Its been bugging me a lot and I don't know if it's an issue within my settings or an issue with VS code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I suspected that I had set a default directory for my linux bash so that whenever I opened a new terminal it would open in a default directory.

That was conflicting with VS code's default behaviour.

To fix :

1. open a new terminal and at root, run
   `$ code ~/.bashrc`
2. search for your default directory
   it looked like this:
   `$ cd directory-name`
3. simply remove this line, save and close this file.
4. reload VS code and voila

Answer (score 0):

As OP has noted, vscode is conflicting with bash's behaviour, but it is not necessary to give up your bash default cwd (current working directory).

Simply check [whether the terminal is launched by vscode](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134191) and based on that set the default cwd:

```
# ~/.bashrc
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" != "vscode" ]]; then
    cd /default-path
fi
```

now bash will have the `/default-path` as its default cwd and vscode will keep its own project directory.